# Incorrect rows returned with date condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that left joins two table with a date condition. I want to fetch rows for yesterday's transactions only.

Here the query:

When I add the AND condition still all the rows are returned but with null values to those not matching condition.

```
SELECT  
B.txn_id,
B.txn_time,
B.svc_method,
B.customer_number,
B.amount,
B.amount_commission,
B.status,

A.partner_txn_id,
A.session_id as partner_session_id 

FROM Partner A
LEFT JOIN Transaction B
ON A.log_id = B.txn_id 
AND B.txn_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should either change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN

or

move the call to WHERE section

```
B.txn_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks! don't know how I missed that

Comment: Keeping the LEFT JOIN but moving the condition to the WHERE clause looks like a programming error to me... Simply switch to INNER JOIN instead.